# Google Analytics Funnel Step not appearing in Goal Flow

Tags: google-analytics

I set up my GA Goals to include funnels, and the configuration is as follows:-

1. Application Details - /application
2. User Details - /application/user
3. **Goal: /application/confirmation**

The steps are appearing in the Funnel (though with 0 traffic on each step except the goal), but they are not appearing in the Goal Flow.

The Goal Flow only shows Step 1 and 3.

Any ideas why Step 2 is missing?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your goal configuration?

Comment: My guess is that there's a problem with your config, but can't confirm until we see it.